# yii2: Yii\db\Query in Model function

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am trying create a query in one of my model.php

The query is like

```
public function getBedCategory(){
     $query = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select('room_category')
    ->from('room_charges') 
    ->innerJoin('patient_detail', 
   'patient_detail.bed_type = room_charges.room_name')
   ->where(['room_charges.room_name'=> 'patient_detail.bed_type',
   'patient_detail.id'=> $this->id]);
   $command = $query->createCommand();
   $rows = $command->queryOne();
   //var_dump($command);exit;
   return $rows;
   }
```

When doing a var_dump for $command  I am getting the sql query like this:

```
SELECT `room_category` FROM `room_charges` 
INNER JOIN `patient_detail` ON patient_detail.bed_type = room_charges.room_name 
WHERE (`room_charges`.`room_name`=:qp0) AND (`patient_detail`.`id`=:qp1)
```

and on var_dump of $rows I am getting boolean:false

What I am doing wrong here and why I am getting this :qp0 and :qp1

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: What is ```patient_detail.bed_type```in your ```where``` condition? ```:qp0```and ```:qp1```are place holders for your query parameters that will be replaced with values that you provided in your ```where```condition.

Comment: `patient_detail.bed_type`  is of type integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tahir correctly stated `:qp0` and `:qp1` are place holders for the parameters. These are replaced by static values on execution of the query. Your problem is that `patient_detail.bed_type` should not be parametized. Your code should therefore read:

```
...
->where(['room_charges.room_name = patient_detail.bed_type',
'patient_detail.id'=> $this->id]);
```

For more information on `where()`, you can view [the API page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where%28%29-detail).