# Why does this $year variable changes

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have code below, But why does this query builder passed the $year variable as `:qp0`?

```
$year = 2022;    

$users = (new \yii\db\Query())->from('v_running_table')
         ->where(['run_confirm_year' => $year])->groupBy(['username']);
```

Why does this produce this sql.

```
SELECT * FROM `v_running_table` WHERE `run_confirm_year` = :qp0 GROUP BY `username`
```

Comment: the `:qp0` is a placeholder, see [previous qa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27551917).

Comment: @BagusTesa i ended up writing them down as a php concat rather than as above, still cant wrap my head around what was the issue with how i wrote above but thanks lots!

Comment: @yai You should read something about bind params. For example https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/bind-parameters

Comment: I gave it a read and going to try implementing them later on in my current project. That was helpful, thanks @MichalHynčica !